# Does the definition of incremental ratio really make sense?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

Given f(x), whith x as independent variable.

We know, by definition of derivative as limit of incremental ratio:

f'(x) = lim ( 1/h * (f(x+h) - f(x))) as h-->0

In this definition at numerator we have f(x = x+h) - f(x = x), which seems have no sense to me because x is already the independent variable, but here we are saying: "the independent variable x is assuming the values x+h (i.e. itself + h) and x (i.e itself) respectively". How can this be possibly correct? There is a conflict between the variable and the value assumed by the variable itself!

Answer (score 2):

You are using "$x$" with two separate meanings when you write
$$
f(x = x+h) .
$$
That expression makes no sense.

I suggest you try to think about functions *without thinking about variables*. A function $f$ is a machine  that converts any input number to an output number.(*)

For example, consider the function "square the input to get the output". You can write that with the suggestive expression
$$
f( \ ) = (\ )^2
$$
on the understanding that "$f$" is the *name* of this particular machine, and to get the value of its output for any given input you insert that input into the empty parentheses in the formula on the right.

Then for example
$$
f(2) = (2)^2
$$
and
$$
f(@) = (@)^2, f(x) = (x)^2
$$
(assuming "$@$" and "$x$" actually name some numbers).

You can draw the graph of the function whose machine squares its input by plotting all the points like $(1,1)$ and $(2,4)$ and $(\pi, \pi^2)$.
Once you understand that idea, with no need for variables, you can go back the convention that we usually call a typical point on the horizontal  axis "$x$". Then the graph is just all the points $(x,x^2)$.

Now ordinary algebra tells you
$$
f(x+h) = (x+h)^2 = x^2 + 2xh + h^2 .
$$
which means that the point on the graph above the point on the axis at $x+h$ is higher by $2xh + h^2$ than the point on the graph above $x$.

(*) There's a more formal definition of "function" that you may learn some day, but I think this is the one you need to understand beginning calculus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yea i understood the concept of function as sort of black box which makes some operation on your input without necessity of variables. I know also the specific defintion you are referring to. My doubt was just a matter of form, i still don't understand why, if we call "x" the independent variable, we can let "x" assume the value "x+h": i mean just by a formal point of view, shouldn't be more correct to introduce a new variable (e.g. z) and let x assume a value z+h? I tell this because x+h is meant to be a specific point of the x axis, while x is the name of variable.

Comment: In a formal definition of a function there is no such thing as a "variable". You can talk about "the function $f$"" but you can't formally talk about "the function $f(x)$" because $f(x)$ is a number, not a function. It's the value of the function $f$ at the number $x$. You can (and, formally, must) specify which numbers are allowed as inputs = the set that's the domain of the function. But nothing in that definition specifies a symbol to use for a typical member of the domain.